# How to figure out how many entries are in a relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, matrix-equations

I have the domain $A = \{1, 2, \ldots , 1000\}$.  I need to figure out how many non zero entries are in each relation:

a. $R_1 = \{\;(a, b) \;|\; a \le b\;\}$
b. $R_2 = \{\;(a, b) \;|\; a + b = 1000\;\}$
c. $R_3 = \{\;(a, b) \;|\; a + b \le 1001\;\}$

I did these entries for $A = \{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ and got for (a.) $55$ because you get a $10\times 10$ matrix and you get $10$ 1's for the first column, then $9$ in the next and so on.

For (b.) I did the same.  I shrunk the relation down so I could do it on paper so used $A = \{1,2,\ldots,10\}$, and used this relation $R_2 = \{\;(a, b)\;|\; a + b = 10\}$. I got $9$ 1 entries because in each row there was only one pair of numbers that would equal $10$, so I got $91=100-9$ zero entries.

I did the same thing for (c.) and got $55$ again.  I just need help on expanding these relations, so I can get the value of the entries above.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'non zero entries are in each relation'? The relation contains pairs of objects,  not numbers...

Comment: I suspect $A$ is a domain, on which you define some relations (e.g. $R_1,R_2,R_3$).  It's hard to know what you mean by getting a $10\times 10$ matrix, or what shrinking the relation "down" refers to.  Please explain what you mean.

Comment: Yes I know, I mean in an adjacency matrix of this relation, how many non zero entries are there.

Comment: Doesn't your matrix contain exactly as many non-zero entries as there are pairs contained in the relation (represented as a set of ordered pairs)?

Comment: For each problem I tried to make it more simple so I could draw it on paper to look at non zero entries, and I used  A = {1,2,3...10} and the relations were R1 = {(a, b)| a ≤ b} b. R2 = {(a, b)| a + b = 10} c. R3 = {(a, b)| a + b ≤ 11}.  But I need to know how many are in the adjacency matrix for the set A = {1,2,3..1000}.

Comment: Okay, but pick one of your questions and try to solve it without drawing everything.  If it helps you to mentally picture $R_1 = \{(a,b)\in A \; : \; a \le b \}$ as a matrix, that's fine.  But you know these "non-zero entries" are some fraction of the $1000\times 1000$ possible ordered pairs.  How many of them are there?

Answer (score 1):

You are generally on the right track.  The easiest set to count is the relation $R_2$ of part (b.).  How many $a\in A$ allow for $b\in A$ such that $a+b=1000$?  Since zero is not in $A$, only $999$ of the elements $a\in A$ allow this, and there is clearly exactly one $b = 1000-a$ for each such $a$.

Similar to what you found for the simple case with ten elements in $A$, the counts for $R_1$ and $R_3$ will be equal.  This is because $a \le b$ in $A$ is equivalent to:

$$ a + (1001 - b) \le 1001 $$

That is, $(a,b) \in R_1$ if and only if $(a,1001-b) \in R_3$.  If you verify that $b\in A$ if and only if $1001-b \in A$, then you should be convinced the relation $R_3$ has exactly the same number of ordered pairs as $R_1$ does.